# Passing parameter to divide field value to stored procedure makes it slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Recently I made a change to my stored procedure to pass a parameter value to divide the value of one of the fields... and stored procedure became very slow. It was taking 1 minute to run 600 recs and now its taking 8-9 minutes to run same results. Could you please help improve this little change?

I only added the following line in the select list

```
(nullif(x.tardies, 0) / @addtardies) addtardies
```

Here's the complete code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[z_testCalc]
    (
        @calendarID     int,
        @grade          varchar(3),
        @AbsType        varchar(1),
        @Tardies        varchar(1),
        @startDate      smallDateTime,
        @endDate        smallDateTime,
        @TeamActivity   varchar(50),
        @Percent        VARCHAR(10),
        @AddTardies int
    )   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select distinct
        x.test1,
        x.test2, 
        x.AbsType,
        x.UnexAbs,
        x.ExAbs,
        x.Tardies, 
        mp.meetings,
        round((1 - cast(x.UnexAbs as decimal(6,3))/cast(mp.meetings as decimal(6,3))) * 100,1) percentPres,
         **(nullif(x.tardies, 0) / @addtardies) addtardies,**
        x.endDate
    from  
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
                sch.test1,
                p.test1, 
                case when @AbsType = 'T' then 'Unexc, Exc' when @AbsType = 'U' then 'Unexc' else 'Exc' end 'AbsType',
                sum(case when COALESCE(x.status, a.status) = 'A' and CASE WHEN a.excuseID IS NOT NULL THEN x.excuse ELSE a.excuse END = 'U' then 1 else 0 end) 'UnexAbs',
                sum(case when COALESCE(x.status, a.status) = 'A' and CASE WHEN a.excuseID IS NOT NULL THEN x.excuse ELSE a.excuse END = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) 'ExAbs',
                sum(case when COALESCE(x.status, a.status) = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) 'Tardies',
                ros.endDate
        FROM    
           test1  a WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Another side note: Unless accuracy is not important you should avoid using the NOLOCK hint. It can and will return missing and/or missing data. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: what is the date type of x.tardies?

Comment: thank you @Sean Lange. that's good point.

Comment: @DudiKonfino data type for x.tardies is Integer. thakns.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look to me like a likely scenario for huge parameter sniffing issues.  Still, when introducing a parameter results in bizarre slowdowns like you describe, I always like to rule it out.

Try adding a line that assigns your parameter to a local variable, and then use the local variable, not the parameter, in your query.

so put this at the top, before the query...

```
DECLARE @AddTardies_lcl int
SET @AddTardies_lcl = @AddTardies
```

and then use `@AddTardies_lcl` in your new logic.

```
(nullif(x.tardies, 0) / @AddTardies_lcl) addtardies
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Greenspark. that's good point. I have implemented that in my code. but its very slow...will keep you posted.